# How do I load Ultimate Chicken Horse save data on PS4?

Tags: ps4, ultimate-chicken-horse

I got Ultimate Chicken Horse a long while ago and I've got a bit of a problem. I don't know how to load the save data!

I've played this game a lot with my brother but every time we start up the game all of our unlocks are gone.

Does anyone know where all this data goes after every playthrough on a PlayStation 4?

Edit: I have located the save data but have no way to use it.